# VM Deployment and RoleInstance Count - Azure REST API

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-management

I'm using Azure Management Libraries and want to restart a VM. Yet I have some question below about VMs on Azure. As you know a VM is also a cloud service. Therefore I'm getting the entire hosted service list and filter by RoleType = "PersistentVMRole" to get VMs list. Here are my questions:

1. Does a VM have only one deployment slot named "Production"?
2. Can a VM have more than one RoleInstance?

Can anyone clarify me about this?

Thanks,
Abdurrahman

Answer (score 1):

1º As for the first question I don't understand what you mean by "one deployment slot". Deployment slots can be either Production or Stagin in Azure.

2º For the second answer you can check this SO question: [Is a Windows Azure worker role instance a whole VM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925218/is-a-windows-azure-worker-role-instance-a-whole-vm), by the way, the answer is **no**.

Comment: Thanks for the second question. In the first question I mean that I'm getting the virtual machine list and all of their deployment slots seem as Production. I think VMs have only Production slot but cloud services can have both production and staging. Is it true?

Comment: Yes, exactly! The Cloud Service acts as a container for virtual machines. Within a cloud service there are two slots for deployments for traditional web and worker roles Staging and Production. With virtual machines the Production slot is the only one in use (VIP swapping is not supported with VMs). Taken from http://michaelwasham.com/2012/06/08/understanding-windows-azure-virtual-machines/